# Combine dataframe based on index R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two dataframes,

```
df1

Month Type Count
Jan   t1   1
Feb   t2   0
Mar   t3   1

df2

Answer
2
3
```

Now, in the df2 I have answers for all the records in df1 which has Count 1. So I want to merge and get something like this.

```
df3

Month Type Count Answer
Jan   t1   1     2
Feb   t2   0     0
Mar   t3   1     3
```

Problem is that the index for both the dataframes are different. And df1 has more records than df2. So I am not able to join based on index or merge. How do I achieve this?

Comment: How is the order of the answer defined? i.e. how should we know 2 belongs to the 1st row while 3 belongs to the 3rd row?

Comment: Alright, so df2 is exactly in the same order as df1 except that this dataframe has no records for records with Count = 0 in df1.

Comment: If that is the case, and the length of the answer is equal to the number of rows where `count == 1`, then you can probably do `df1$Answer = 0; df1$Answer[df1$Count == 1] = df2$Answer`

Comment: Perfect. Can you write it as an answer rather than a comment? I can accept it and close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a column of zeros for `df1` and then update values where `count == 1` with the answer from `df2`:

```
df1$Answer <- 0
df1$Answer[df1$Count == 1] <- df2$Answer

df1
#  Month Type Count Answer
#1   Jan   t1     1      2
#2   Feb   t2     0      0
#3   Mar   t3     1      3
```

Comment: No problem. Glad to help :)

Comment: I can only say a little bit. Why not ask the question on SO or SE? there must be a lot ready to help.

Comment: Yeah, I posted in SO yesterday, since I dont any experience on that field, not able to proceed further. Here is that -- > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38840645/optimization-objective-function

Answer (score 1):

We can use the assignment in place with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Answer := 0L][Count == 1, Answer := df2$Answer][]
#   Month Type Count Answer
#1:   Jan   t1     1      2
#2:   Feb   t2     0      0
#3:   Mar   t3     1      3
```